# Running keep-lines command on all opened buffers in emacs

Tags: emacs, buffer, emacs24

I have many files opened in `emacs` buffers. Now I want to run `keep-lines` command on all this opened buffer.

What is steps for doing this?

I am using emacs version 24.3.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all opened buffers: Use `dolist` to iterate over `buffer-list` (or any suitable subset you like).  Use `with-current-buffer` for the current iteration's buffer, and call `keep-lines` inside that.

You can tweak it to have more flexibility (e.g., in the `keep-lines` call):

```
(defun foo (regexp)
  (interactive (list (read-regexp "Regexp: ")))
  (dolist (buf  (buffer-list))
    (goto-char (point-min)) ; Is this what you want, to start at bob?
    (with-current-buffer buf (keep-lines regexp))))
```

However, `buffer-list` returns many buffers that you probably do not want to do this to.  Filter it as needed, e.g., using `remove-if` (in `cl-lib.el`) or whatever.

If you deal only with file buffers, then you might want to use `find-file-noselect`. There are multiple possibilities, depending on what you really need.

You can practice with something like this:

```
(defun foo (regexp)
  (interactive (list (read-regexp "Regexp: ")))
  (dolist (buf  (buffer-list))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (when (y-or-n-p (format "Do it to `%s'? " buf))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (keep-lines regexp)))))
```

And then you might want to think about whether you also want to save the modified buffer, etc.

Comment: I'm curious why someone downvoted this answer.  Something incorrect about it?

Comment: Don't worry, mine was down-voted as well. We're victims of the Stack Overflow equivalent of a drive-by shooting with a water-pistol  :)

Answer (score 1):

For a more manually-controlled approach, you might use `ibuffer`:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ibuffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- Mark some buffers
- <kbd>E</kbd> `(keep-lines "pattern")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Or, as per Drew's suggestion, `(progn (goto-char (point-min)) (keep-lines "pattern"))`

You can mark buffers using lots of different criteria in ibuffer. Browse the "Mark" menu, and see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> for details.